Highcharts polar spider with Min and Max for each y-axis, but only one series of data
I am designing a radar chart that reflects various abilities of a person. Usually, the maximum value for each aspect is 100, but sometimes I want different abilities to have different maximum values, such as 30 or 25. Can I achieve this using the Highcharts radar chart?

Do you want to set the maximum for several series on one chart or for several separate charts? Because the maximum value refers to the axis (yAxis.max): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eknos19z/

@Michał Thanks for the fast reply. I want to set several series on one chart.

Do you have a design of what it looks like because it's a bit hard for me to imagine what it would look like. It is possible to set several separate axes so that they overlap, but it would probably not be visually clear
